# Migrating WebSphere 9 ant tasks to WebSphere liberty

Tags: ant, websphere, websphere-liberty

I am trying to migrate j2ee application from WebSphere to liberty.

The build script uses WebSphere specific ant tasks (com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.WsEjbDeploy) in the ant build scripts

Is there any similar task available for liberty ? or

Can the code build using the above task be deployed and will work on liberty?

Answer (score 1):

EJBDeploy and the associated ant task have been replaced by a Just-In-Time (JIT) deployment feature. This capability was first introduced in WebSphere traditional version 7.0 for all EJB 3 (and later) modules.

Liberty provides JIT deployment for all EJB module levels (EJB 1.x through EJB 3.2).
WebSphere traditional now also supports JIT deployment of all EJB module versions, as of versions 8.5.5.16 and 9.0.5.0, except for modules containing EJB 1.x or 2.x Entity beans.  Entity beans still require the use of EJBDeploy. If your application contains Entity beans, they will need to be converted to another form of persistence, such as JPA, when migrating to Liberty.

When migrating an application to Liberty that used EJBDeploy on WebSphere traditional, the non-deployed version of the application should be used. Do not migrate the artifacts generated by EJBDeploy to Liberty. The JIT deployment capability of Liberty will dynamically generate the artifacts in memory as needed. It is possible the EJBDeploy generated artifacts may interfere with proper behavior in Liberty.

For more information about JIT deployment, see the following information in the knowledge center:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/cejb_deployejbfp.html

If the application contains remote EJB interfaces and a thin client will be used, then Stub classes will need to be generated for packaging with the thin client. This would have been done by EJBDeploy previously, but now may be accomplished by using RMIC.

More information about deploying remote interfaces to Liberty may be found from a link provided here :

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_ejb_dev.html